# Saving Object getting attributes back Java

Tags: java, arraylist, save

I would need your help on following question: When saving object in ArrayList, is it possible to get its attributes back as string.

For example :

```
public class SimpleClass {
    private String Name;
    public SimpleClass(String name) {
        super();
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Instances of object above are saved in `ArrayList`. How do I get the variable "name" back? If that is not possible, do you think that i should create an ArrayList with that will be filled with String generated from getter ? I am getting hascode back when i read this array and i simply dont  know how to proceed.

Comment: You have a `private` field with no accessor. Add an accessor (a getter), **or** `Override` `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a getter method to your class as @Elliott Frisch mentioned.

```
public class SimpleClass {
    private String name;
    public SimpleClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 
}
```

Then call it from your `ArrayList`

```
String name = arrayList.get(index).getName();
```

This will return you the `name` value.

Answer (score 0):

Use getter and setter to modify and access private fields. Good OOP practice.

```
public class SimpleClass {
    private String Name;

    public SimpleClass(String name) {
        super();
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

You can get a name for an instance of `SimpleClass` using `getName()`. Also, you don't require a call to `super` here since you aren't extending any class (other than `object`).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to name with lowercase and do it like this

```
public class SimpleClass {
  private String name;
  public SimpleClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

   public String getName() {
    return this.name;
 } 
}
```